# Shell_exec nohup with nohup.out

Tags: php, shell, nohup

Executing this code:

```
shell_exec('nohup command&');
```

or this

```
shell_exec('nohup command > /path/to/nohup.out 2>&1&');
```

But there is no nohup.out in both cases. How can I run nohup with nohup.out via php?

Comment: The second one should absolutely have created that file (whether or not `nohup` or `command` actually ran in fact). Are you sure it didn't create the file? (Or did you mean that  the file was empty?)

Comment: Does the server you're running this on allow `shell_exec()` to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shell_exec('nohup command > /path/to/nohup.out 2>&1&');

This line will work. Just make sure you have write permissions for the output folder. Consider your output folder is /usr/nohup-out

```
ls -l /usr/nohup-out
```

It should have write, read and execute permissions (**rwx**). If not, do this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/nohup-out
```

Now, try to execute php file. It should create a nohup file in `/usr/nohup-out` folder.

**Sample script and result:**

**1. date.php:**

```
<?php
shell_exec('nohup date > /usr/nohup-out/nohup.out 2>&1&');
?>
```

**2. Execute php from terminal:**

```
php date.php
```

**3. nohup.out content after execution**

> Thu Apr 23 11:30:28 IST 2015

Comment: > Just make sure you have write permissions for the output folder    -  and this is the solution, thank you.